# JQuery, вывод данных, полученных из ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Как правильно дополнять содержимое дива данными, полученными $.ajax ?

```
function reload(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/chat/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $('.chat-text').html(key + " " + value)
            })
        }
    })
}
<div class="chat-text"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Проблема, как оказалось, была совсем в другом:
     function reload(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/chat/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('.chat_text').append(key + " " + value)
                })
            }
        })
    }

Comment: Спасибо всем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/chat/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    context: $('.chat-text'), // указываем контекст
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, $.proxy(function(key, value){
            this.append(key + " " + value); // используем указанный контекст
        }, this));
    }
})
```

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions)
- [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: Все равно не помогает, в консоли четко вижу что данные приходят, но добавление в div не наблюдается

Comment: proxy тоже не помогает. я в растерянности

Answer (score 1):

[.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) ?

Comment: Пробовал, все равно не срабатывает

Comment: "не срабатывает" это мало чем поможет вам помочь, подробнее опишите

Comment: Не знаю, как же подробней можно описать процесс. В браузер data приходит, но изменений страницы не вижу. Пробовал 
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
                    this.append("trololo")
                })
Ноль реакции

Comment: не знаю, попробуйте простись по `data` в цикле `for` вместе `$.each`, да и в указаном вами участке кода `this.append` - вызовит ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов может быть полно. Попробуйте вместо класса указать идентификатор слоя. Если нужно строго с классов, вы уверены, что у вас единственный элемент на странице с таким классом?

Comment: Да, элемент единственный. А идентификатор слоя это "id"?

Comment: Да, попробуйте:
<div id="chat-text"> ... </div>
а потом 
$("#chat-text").append(key + " " + value)

Comment: По id тоже нет

Comment: Чем вы пользуетесь для отладки?

Comment: firebug в firefox'e

Comment: Попробуйте сделать то же самое старым дедовским способом:).
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
$('.chat-text').append(data[i].key + " " + data[i].value);
}
Вроде не ошибся в синтаксисе.

Comment: Ой, не обратил внимание, что уже такое посоветовали.